# Errors during Tailwind 2.1 + Rails 6 + React setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css, webpacker

Okay,

It's the 4th time I go to the internet in search of answers of how to setup Tailwind 2.1 properly.

In my configuration, I have a Rails 6 Project, configured with Webpacker 6 (Beta), Webpack 5, React and Sass.

I've tried to follow Tailwind guide to configure Postcss but it didn't worked.

To make this communication easier, I've hosted a simple repository with my project.
https://github.com/renatodex/rails6-tailwind21-webpacker6-webpack-5

When I run webpack-dev-server, I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./app/packs/entrypoints/hello_react.pcss 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> @import "tailwindcss/base";
|
| @import "tailwindcss/components";

webpack 5.39.1 compiled with 1 error in 1929 ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

However, as you can see, postconfig is already configured properly with the tailwind postcss plugin:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3
    }),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
}
```

It should be working, right? I have no idea what I am doing wrong. :(

My goal is simple:

- Setup a fully functional Rails 6 project, using Tailwind 2.1 with JIT (Just in Time) and React, using Rails Webpacker.

I appreciate your patience very much for reading and trying to help me on this!

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to say that your way is wrong, but I have always seen the directory structure along the lines of

```
app/javascript/packs/application.js
app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss
```

with an import line in application.js

`import "../stylesheets/application"`

The first 3 lines of my application.scss are:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

You can specify a location for the tailwind.config.js in the postcss file (I keep mine in the stylesheets directory as above).

To enable the JIT have the following lines in the tailwind.config.js  .  The mode: "jit" tells tailwind to jit and the purge line tells it where you keep your view files for it to base the jit on.

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: ["./app/views/**/*"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwUpnXumcw4)

I think you are missing some important things in your application.js.  This is mine, which you may find useful for reference.

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"
import "stimulus"

Rails.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

import "../stylesheets/application"

import "controllers"
const images = require.context("../images", true)
```

Good travels!